# Is the API for MS Dynamics the same between 2011, 2013 and hosted vs onprem

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone know if the API for Dynamics is the same for 2011 and 2013 or there are any differences between a hosted and on-premise install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the API (client-side and server-side) are the same between CRM 2011, CRM 2013 OnPremise e CRM Online.
Some API has been introduced in later rollups (like the `ExecuteMultipleRequest` shipped with Rollup 12) or with CRM 2013 (like the `Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification()` JavaScript).

CRM Online has also some limitations, like plugins and workflows only in sandbox and the FetchXML-only for Reports.